# Show PDF in RadPdfViewer from URL in WinForm

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, pdf, telerik

I'm using RadPdfViewer first time in my WinForm application. I want to load pdf from url (e.g. http://10.70.0.60/PDF/sample.pdf ).

Its working with local file but not with website url of PDF file, I have mentioned in example.
Kindly please suggest me how I load PDF from url in RadPdfViewer Control.Kindly let me know if any other detail required.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://www.telerik.com/forums/load-files-from-external-server-in-radpdfviewer

Comment: thanks for link . @Nikhil V

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the issue by my self. Hope this answer will save next person time. Below code is working fine for me.

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            using (Stream ms = new MemoryStream(client.DownloadData("http://10.70.0.60/PDF/sample.pdf")))
            {
                MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();
                mStream.SetLength(ms.Length);
                ms.Read(mStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)ms.Length);
                this.radPdfViewer1.LoadDocument(mStream);                    
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set Documentsource as shows, Wroked for me

```
 PDFViewer.DocumentSource = new PdfDocumentSource(new Uri(@"YOUR PATH");
```

Comment: This does not work for the Winforms widget, only the WPF widget supports this property.